# Left adjoint functor and corepresentablility

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{A,B}$ be categories, $G:\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$ be functor. How do I prove that $G$ has a left adjoint iff $\mathrm{Hom}(X,G(-))$ is corepresentable?

Comment: corepresentable?

Comment: @LorenoHeer $F$ is corepresentable iff $F\simeq \mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$ for some $X$.

Comment: @uijokbijk So $X$ is also a functor?

Comment: @Sanath No, $X$ is an object...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh, whoops, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the statement to be:

Suppose $G:A\to B$ and let $X\in B$ and suppose $F \dashv G$. Then, $\hom (X,G-)$ is representable $\forall X\in B$, and conversely.

One direction is trivial because by adjointness we have that the pair $(FX,\phi )$ where

$\phi:\hom (FX,-)\to \hom (X,G-)$ is a representation of $\hom (X,G-)$ because $\phi $ is a natural isomorphism.

On the other hand, if $(A,\phi )$ and $(A',\phi' )$are representations of $\hom (X,G-)$ and $\hom (Y,G-)$, repsectively, then $\phi :\hom (A,-)\to \hom (X,G-)$ and $\phi' :\hom (A',-)\to \hom (Y,G-)$ are natural isomorphisms.

We now define $F:B\to A$ by $FX=A$ on objects.

To obtain $F$ on arrows $f:X\to Y$ consider $\phi _{FY}:\hom (FX,FY)\to \hom (X,GFY)$ and $\phi' _{FY}(1_{FY})$ and take $Ff=\phi^{-1} _{FY}\left ( \phi' _{FY}(1_{FY})\circ f \right )$.

You can check that $F$ is a functor and that $F \dashv G$.

Comment: Were you trying to write $F \dashv G$ (produced with `F \dashv G`) in your second paragraph? I have never seen your notation for adjoint functors before.

Comment: yes indeed thank you. I have fixed the notation